# How to avoid adding duplicate of element.Laravel, PHP

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, web

Shortly, there are teachers and i have to attach them courses. Every course should be added once only(not twice). My code is working but only for **element** with **id=1**.And **the other courses** can be attached to a teacher **more than once**. I am writing the code in laravel. (php).
I can't uderstand why it is working only for the first element(course($id=1)).
Can you help me please. Where is my mistake?? Thank You in advance.
Here is my code. To One Teacher, many different courses should be attached. But not one course twice!

```
public function addCourse($id, Request $request) {
        $teacher = Teacher::findOrFail($id);
        if($teacher->has('courses')->where('id', $request->get('course_id'))->get()->isEmpty()) {
            $teacher->courses()->attach($request->get('course_id'));

        }
         else {
            flash()->error('This Course has been added already!')->important();
        }


        return back();
    }
```

Comment: use `sync()` or `detach()` before `attach()`

Comment: Mcklayin, thank you for your answer! But where do you mean, how to use them?

Comment: I think you should let MySQL handle this and add a UNIQUE index on i asume the table columns course_id and teacher_id this way you cant get duplicates

Comment: If every course is only attached once, why aren't you using a BelongsTo/HasMany relationship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To attach a one to many

```
$teacher = Teacher::findOrFail($id);
$course = Course::findOrFail($request->get('course_id'));

$course->teacher()->associate($teacher);;
$course->save();
```

Comment: I have to attach one to many. What can you suggest? sync() is working bu it is detaching other courses of the teacher! Thank you

Comment: I show you how to link many, didn't I? Use `syncWithoutDettaching()`, it won't dettach anything as the name suggests. By the way, are you sure you have a many to many relationship?

Comment: I need ONE TO MANY. I have one to many relationships!
I used  this way you showed,  $teacher = Teacher::findOrFail($id);
$teacher->courses()->sync([ $request->get('course_id') ]);
 As I said it is working sync() is adding one course only once. But it is dettaching the other courses of that teacher!

Comment: OMG you have been confusing everyone with your queries. These queries are for many to many. For one to many you do it differently. I update my code.

Comment: Nope. it was working just before your editing last time! That time i marked it  as correct answer, then again unselected it ))). But I got the answer thank you. It is working!

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is an issue in how you are querying.

When you do this...

```
$teacher->has('courses')->where('id', $request->get('course_id'))
```

That `->where()` is still looking at the `teachers` table, not the courses table.  I think what you really want to do is use a `whereHas` to determine if the teacher has that course.

```
$hasCourse = Teacher::whereHas('courses', function($q) use ($request) {
    // Here we can add constraints on the courses table
    $q->where('id', $request->get('course_id'));
})->where('id', $id)->exists();

if (! $hasCourse) {
    $course = Course::findOrFail($request->get('course_id'));
    $course->teacher()->associate($id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

PROBLEM SOLVED. I  used

> `$teacher->courses()->sync([$request->get('course_id')],$detaching =
>   false);`

Finally i have this script:

> ```
> > public function addCourse($id, Request $request) {
> >         $teacher = Teacher::findOrFail($id);
> >         $teacher->courses()->sync([$request->get('course_id')],$detaching =
> > false);
> >         
> >         return back();
> >     }
> ```

Thank you all.